# Сохранить преобразованное изображение в файл

Tags: python, opencv

После преобразования исходного *.jpg файла, методом "опорного белого цвета" (идея [отсюда](https://jmanansala.medium.com/image-processing-with-python-color-correction-using-white-balancing-6c6c749886de))

```
def whitepatch_balancing(image, from_row, from_column, row_width, column_width):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))
    ax[0].imshow(image)
    ax[0].add_patch(Circle((from_column, from_row),
                              linewidth=3,
                              edgecolor='r', facecolor='none'));

    ax[0].set_title('Original image')
    image_patch = image[from_row:from_row+row_width, from_column:from_column+column_width]
    image_max = (image*1.0 / image_patch.max(axis=(0, 1))).clip(0, 1)
    ax[1].imshow(image_max);
    ax[1].set_title('Whitebalanced Image with MAX value of white')
    plt.show()
    return image_max

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = imread('img.jpg')
    balanced_img = whitepatch_balancing(image, 60, 1230, 20, 20)
```

если исходная картика (в формате RGB) имела такой вид: [[[131 152 205],  [120 143 195],    ...,  [135 150 191]]]

то получившийся после преобразования, массив имеет примерно такой вид: [[[0.99242424 0.98701299 1.        ],  [0.90909091 0.92857143 1.        ], ...,   [0.84090909 0.64285714 0.21025641]]]

с помощью matplotlib.pyplot as plt можно отобразить картинку и видно, что цветокоррекция произошла [image: отображение исходной и преобразованной картинки]

но если попытаться сохранить преобразованный массив в файл *.jpg или *.png - получим просто черную картику (все значения пикселей меньше единицы)

как можно адекватно сохранить получившийся результат (преобразованную картинку) в файл ?

Comment: plt.save пробовали?

Comment: судя по симптомам, у вас просто на выходе нормализованное изображение (vmin=0, vmax=1). просто умножьте массив на 255 и переведите в целые.

Comment: нет, не save, а imsave()
plt.imsave('image.img', balanced_img)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Умножь все значения на 255.

Или поправь строчку

```
image_max = (image*1.0 / image_patch.max(axis=(0, 1))).clip(0, 1)
```

чтобы получались обычные значения, а не от 0 до 1.

Comment: Спасибо, все правильно, умножить все значения на 255 и округлить, вот так:

    scaleArr = np.dot(balanced_img, 255
    rounded_scaleArr = np.rint(scaleArr)